# Remove from ArrayList one maximum and minimum value

Tags: java, collections

I have ArrayList with random Integers. How can I remove from this list one minmum value and maximum value?

```
List < Integer > theBigList = new ArrayList <> ();
        Random theGenerator = new Random();
        for (int n = 0; n < 14; n++) {

            theBigList.add(theGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1);
        };
```

I used method Colections.max nad minimum but I think it removes all of maximum and minimum values from ArrayList.

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: maybe u want to take a look at this [Remove first N selectively from list using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780775/remove-first-n-selectively-from-list-using-java-8/37792986#:~:text=List%20mylist%20%3D%20new,(%22all%22)%3B%20mylist.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With streams:

```
// removes max
theBigList.stream()
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())   
        .ifPresent(theBigList::remove);

// removes min
theBigList.stream()
        .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())   
        .ifPresent(theBigList::remove);
```

Without streams:

```
// removes max
if(!theBigList.isEmpty()) {
    theBigList.remove(Collections.max(theBigList));
}

// removes min
if(!theBigList.isEmpty()) {
    theBigList.remove(Collections.min(theBigList));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this.  The point to remember is that `List.remove(int)` removes the value at that index where `List.remove(object)` removes the object.

```
List<Integer> theBigList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(10,20,30));

if (theBigList.size() >= 2) {
    Integer max = Collections.max(theBigList);
    Integer min = Collections.min(theBigList);

    theBigList.remove(max);
    theBigList.remove(min);
}
System.out.println(theBigList);
```

Prints

```
[20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List< Integer > theBigList = new ArrayList<>();
        theBigList.remove(
             theBigList
             .stream()
             .mapToInt(v -> v)
             .max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new));
        theBigList.remove(
             theBigList
                  .stream()
                  .mapToInt(v -> v)
                  .min().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new));
```