# Making input ignoring lower or upper case

Tags: java

I created a list of items with an option to remove or modify one of these items.
so lets say I am adding item with upper case ("Milk)"
then trying to remove "milk" it wont let me.
Tried to play with some toUpperCase or toLowerCase sadly with no succees.

in main class:

```
    public static void removeItem() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the item you want to remove");
    String itemToRemove = in.next();
    groceryList.removeItem(itemToRemove);
}
```

in List class:

```
  public void removeItem(String itemToRemove) {
    if (groceryList.contains(itemToRemove)) {
        groceryList.remove(itemToRemove);
        System.out.println("You've removed " + itemToRemove + " from the list!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The item you've entered are not in the list!");
    }
}
```

output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for items using contains() and remove() method. You will need to use a brute force approach like :

```
 public void removeItem(String itemToRemove) {
    int i=0;
    while(i<list.size()){
    if (list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(itemToRemove)){
        list.remove(i);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

In order to be able to use contains and remove method to handle thse cases, you will need to create an Item class as below and use that in your list.

```
class Item {
  String itemName;
 //add getter and setter
public boolean equals(Object obj){
//add your equals ignore case 
return itemName.equalsIgnoreCase((String)obj);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `List` you could use a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator`:

```
private final Set<String> groceries = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Then you can just rename `groceryList` to `groceries`, and your code should work.

The only downside of using a `Set` is that the order in which the items were added is no longer preserved, and that you can only add an item once.

Answer (score 0):

I will add another option among the good options you have received.

If you want to use a `List<String>`, you can do the following:

```
groceryList.removeIf(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(itemToRemove));
```

(Note that if there are multiple items with that name, it will remove all. In case, you want to remove just one, you can use this [Remove first N selectively from list using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780775/remove-first-n-selectively-from-list-using-java-8))

And to check if the `groceryList` contains the `itemToRemove`:

```
groceryList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(itemToRemove))
```

This option sacrifices time complexity, but it might not matter for your use case.